# How to get computer name or IP from javascript?

Tags: javascript, computer-name, ip-address

I want to get the name of the computer or its IP address through javascript.

How can this be obtained?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Client IP using just Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Comment: @Greg (et. al.): The name part probably makes it distinct enough. Also, he says "through Javascript" but the poster in the other question very clearly says "using no server-side code" which this question leaves open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Imran and Jamie have said, you can't do it entirely on the client.

It's trivial to get the computer's apparent, public IP address — but only if you send a request to your server, either by using `XmlHTTPRequest` or by appending a `script` tag to the `head` section or similar. The server can respond to that request by echoing the IP from which the request apparently came. How you get that information depends on your server-side technology.

That'll get you the IP (using a server request), but I don't know of a way to get the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. JavaScript doesn't have access outside browser's sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript can't do it alone, you have to use JQuery for that below is the code snippet

```
<script>
$.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function (data) {
  console.log("Ip address ====>", data.ip);
})
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).